# It is posible to restart a PCIe card through code (using C, C++ or .NET)?

Tags: c++, c, .net

I have a PCIe card for communications that often gets an error while connecting and, in order to recovering it, is needed to turn off the PC and then turn on again (a restart is not valid).

Is there any way to reset a PCIe card?

It will be interesting a hardware reset (quit and return supply), but even if there is any function for software reset, I would be interested in.

Thank you.

Comment: If you google "reset a PCIe card" you get many hits.

Comment: All I see are Linux commands

Comment: You didn't look enough: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203316/reset-fpga-based-pcie-card-and-restore-its-config-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you'd consider software resets, I think it should be pretty obvious that you cannot do this in an application. Hardware is managed by the OS. What would happen if ordinary applications could power down the video card?!

So, the answer (practically speaking) is no. Your purely theoretical chance (Linux is Open Source) is not an option if you're thinking about .Net and thus Windows.